# ASP.NET SQL - Incorrect syntax near '('

Tags: asp.net, sql

```
Guid currentUserID = (Guid)Session["UserId"];
String accomid = (String)Session["AccomID"];
String schdid = (String)Session["SchdID"];
String schdprice = (String)Session["SchdPrice"];
con.Open();

cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Transactions (Accom_ID, UserID, Schd_ID, Trans_CardNo, Trans_CardSecurity, Trans_CardName, Trans_Paid, Trans_Cost) values('" + accomid + "','" + currentUserID + "','" + schdid + "','" + txtCardNumber.Text + "','" + txtCardSecurityNumber.Text + "','" + txtName.Text + "','" + "Yes" + "','" + schdprice + "')", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Schedule (Schd_Avaliable) values('" + "No" + "')", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I'm getting the error

> Incorrect syntax near '('.

If I remove these statements:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Schedule (Schd_Avaliable) values('" + "No" + "')", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get no error. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: You also might want to look into parametrized queries...they're safer and easier to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSERT` and `UPDATE` syntax in SQL is different. Your update should be like this:

```
UPDATE Table SET
   Column = Value
   ,Column2 = Value2
   ,Column3 = Value3
WHERE
    <constraint(s)>
```

You're missing any constraints from your `UPDATE` statement. Executing it the way its written currently would update **every** single row in your table. Also, I would recommend that you change your SQL to use prepared statements. You're currently wide open to SQL injection attacks.

A couple of other things: if you are using Yes/No values, I would recommend switching to using a bit (boolean) column. Are the "Yes" and "No" values going to be dynamic? If not, you don't need to do this:

```
... "'" + "No" + "'" ...
```

You can just do

```
... "'No'" ...
```

And lastly, you have a spelling mistake: "Avaliable" > "Available"

Comment: Hi Cory, thanks for the help, Im not familar with SQL Perpared statements at the moment thats next years module at the moment we are keeping it simple but I have fixed it just unsure how to add the WHERE Ive got cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Schedule SET Schd_Avaliable = '" + "No" + "'", con); Now but I want to add WHERE Schd_ID = schdid; Could you help me string it together?

Comment: Yup, it's simply `SqlCommand("UPDATE Schedule SET Schd_Avaliable = '" + "No" + "' WHERE Schd_ID = " + schdid.ToString(), con);`

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL is wrong.

```
"UPDATE Schedule SET Schd_Available = 'No'"
```

or

```
"UPDATE Schedule SET Schd_Available = '" + "No" + "'"
```

Notice the `SET` and `=`

Answer (score 0):

Update your UPDATE statement to the following.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Schedule SET Schd_Available = '" + "No" + "'", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You might also want to consider a WHERE clause here.  Otherwise Schd_Available wil be set to No for all rows.

For a reference to the UPDATE syntax, check out http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

**EDIT**: Added in the =, originally had it, then changed format and forgot.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: You're missing an `=`. Should be `SET Schd_Available = 'No'`